# I need to make a drop down box with two choices in java

Tags: java

I need to make a drop down box with two choices in java and when either option or word is clicked it runs the program that I have created with else if statements.  Can anyone help??  Right now my program opens each option by inputing 1 or 2.  Want a drop box of some sort instead.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the swing package? In particular, `javax.swing.JComboBox?`

Answer (score 1):

This code will update the label when you use the combobox.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ComboTest extends JFrame {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ComboTest();
  }

  public ComboTest() {
    final JLabel label = new JLabel("Select something in the ComboBox");

    String[] options = {"1", "2"};
    JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(options);
    combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JComboBox cb = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
        String selected = (String) cb.getSelectedItem();
        label.setText("You selected: " + selected);
      }
    });

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    });

    JPanel main = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    main.add(combo, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    main.add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    getContentPane().add(main);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Jorgen this is what I am looking for I think.  Will this open my else statements?  Also, when I past this into my DemandForHealthCare class do I copy the whole thing and paste where?  In place of this?  
String PVal,coinsuranceVal,deductibleVal,insurancetypeVal;


insurancetypeVal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 1 for Deductible payment 2 for Co-Insurance");

insurancetype = Double.parseDouble(insurancetypeVal);

Comment: Or maybe i could e-mail you my program and you could help me get it right?  I would be happy to rate you the best if you could.  It's for a final project due in a couple hours and I can't figure it out :(  Any help from anyone would be great..Leave an e-mail if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/features/components.html) swing visual guide. You could use JComboBox

Comment: Enrique, I looked at the JComboBox first demo (uneditable) at the bottom, this is what I need but not with images.  I need it to open my separate page..Does anyone know how to code this???  I just have 2 else statements to link to the box.

Comment: here is the part of focus...Need to change that input of 1 or 2 into a drop box...

String PVal,coinsuranceVal,deductibleVal,insurancetypeVal;


insurancetypeVal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter 1 for Deductible payment 2 for Co-Insurance");

insurancetype = Double.parseDouble(insurancetypeVal);


if(insurancetype==1) {PVal = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter fee for hospital visit (Ex. $2500)");